# runtime.onMessage sender parameter does not contain the tab info

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a browser action that sends a message

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var message = {
        'message': 'overlay-intent'
    };

    tab_message(tab.id, message);
});

function tab_message(tab_id, message) {
    if (message) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab_id, message);
    }
}
```

And  a listener on my content script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var domain = window.location.host;
    ext_id = sender.id;

    if (request.message === 'overlay-intent') {
        if (is_modal_open()) {
            return close_modal();
        }

        if (csp_blacklist.indexOf(domain) > -1 ) {
            return create_tab();
        }
        var src = build_source(sender.tab.id);
        open_modal(src);
    }
});
```

The problem Im having is that I need the tab is from the current selected tab without having to send another message. I read that sender should have a tab object but it doesnt. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the property `sender` implies [it has information about who *sent* the message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender), not who *received* it.

Since the sender is the background page, you get the wrong result.

Messages can be of any (JSON-compatible) format - it can be an object with as many keys as you like; you should simply include the tab ID in the message:

```
function tab_message(tab_id, message) {
    if (message) {
        message.tabId = tab_id;
        // message becomes {tabId: ..., ...}
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab_id, message);
    }
}
```